# vue tables orderBy fail

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2

I have a problem with vue tables. 
From Laravel I get properly ordered data(see code in Laravel:), and when pass into vue that data fail order (see Fail_description image). 
I need to order data ascending by booking_date to new bookings be in first row.

HTML:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">

                <div class="table">
                    <v-client-table :data="{{json_encode($orders)}}" :columns="headers" :options="options"></v-client-table>
                </div>

                <div class="spinner" v-if="loading">
                    <!--<div class="spinner" v-if="isSending">-->
                    <loader :loading="loading" :color="color" :size="loaderSize" class="text-center"></loader>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Vue:

var app = new Vue({

```
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            headers: ['from', 'booking_date', 'service_date',  '_viewmore'],
            options: {
                headings: {
                    _viewmore: 'View more',
                    from: 'Client name',
                },
                filterable: ['from','email','service_date'],
                orderBy: { 'column': 'booking_date'},
                templates: {
                    _viewmore: function (row) {
                        return '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/bookings/' + row.id + '">View more</a>';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        computed: {
            _orders: function () {
                if( _.isString(this.orders) ) {
                    try {
                        return JSON.parse(this.orders)
                    }
                    catch(e) {
                        return this.orders
                    }
                }

                return this.orders;
            }
        }

    });
```

Laravel:

```
array:10 [▼
    0 => array:7 [▼
      "id" => 23
      "from" => "Charlotte Ferard"
      "email" => "charlotte@ferard.co.uk"
      "service_date" => "22.4.17"
      "service_time" => "09:00 - 10:00"
      "booking_date" => "18.4.17"
    ]
    1 => array:7 [▼
      "id" => 25
      "from" => "Sophia Saunders"
      "email" => "sophia_saunders@example.com"
      "service_date" => "29.4.17"
      "service_time" => "13:00 - 14:00"
      "booking_date" => "18.4.17"
    ]
    2 => array:7 [▼
      "id" => 27
      "from" => "Emma Newell"
      "email" => "emziebob@example.com"
      "service_date" => "30.4.17"
      "service_time" => "12:00 - 13:00"
      "booking_date" => "18.4.17"
    ]
    3 => array:7 [▼
      "id" => 28
      "from" => "Daniel Britz"
      "email" => "britzy4472@example.com"
      "service_date" => "29.4.17"
      "service_time" => "09:00 - 10:00"
      "booking_date" => "18.4.17"
    ]
    4 => array:7 [▼
      "id" => 30
      "from" => "Rico Lengefeld"
      "email" => "ricoandshanti@example.com"
      "service_date" => "22.4.17"
      "service_time" => "09:00 - 10:00"
      "booking_date" => "18.4.17"
    ]
    5 => array:7 [▼
      "id" => 31
      "from" => "Nikos Laleas"
      "email" => "nlaleas@example.com"
      "service_date" => "21.4.17"
      "service_time" => "09:00 - 10:00"
      "booking_date" => "19.4.17"
    ]
    6 => array:7 [▼
      "id" => 37
      "from" => "Samantha Nicklin"
      "email" => "samantha.nicklin@example.com"
      "service_date" => "29.4.17"
      "service_time" => "11:00 - 12:00"
      "booking_date" => "19.4.17"
    ]
    7 => array:7 [▼
      "id" => 41
      "from" => "Gail Mathews"
      "email" => "lipyd@example.com"
      "service_date" => "7.5.17"
      "service_time" => "09:00 - 10:00"
      "booking_date" => "5.5.17"
    ]
    8 => array:7 [▼
      "id" => 43
      "from" => "Miriam Hogan"
      "email" => "fofivecyq@example.com"
      "service_date" => "11.5.17"
      "service_time" => "10:00 - 11:00"
      "booking_date" => "8.5.17"
    ]
    9 => array:7 [▼
      "id" => 51
      "from" => "Yuli Hodge"
      "email" => "tevijiduf@example.com"
      "service_date" => "12.5.17"
      "service_time" => "15:00 - 16:00"
      "booking_date" => "10.5.17"
    ]
  ]
```

[Fail_description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQsnP.png)

Comment: If you're getting it in proper order from Laravel, why do you have an `orderBy` spec?

Comment: I need reverse order and later I need to order by booking date on click asc and desc. In the meantime I'm solve this with other date format(in Laravel), and than orberBy work properly. But I don't have idea why this code want work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`booking_date` is coming through as a string. You would need to convert it to a Date for it to sort properly, date-wise.

Comment: Thank you for help. I was format that string with momentjs and this works. Thank you again. 

booking_date: function (row) {
                            return moment(String(row.booking_date)).format('D.M.YY');
                        },